# "Kernal oops" with everything to do with bluetooth

Tags: kernel, bluetooth, crash

Disclaimer, bluetooth may not be the problem. However, the message box pops up after every time this command executes.

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

The dump file is below:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Sun Mar  3 11:10:03 2019
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000020
 IP: klist_next+0x16/0xd0
 PGD 0 P4D 0 
 Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
 Modules linked in: rfcomm msr vmnet(OE) vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock vmw_vmci vmmon(OE) cmac bnep nls_iso8859_1 btusb btrtl btbcm btintel bluetooth uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core ecdh_generic videodev media snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_soc_skl snd_soc_skl_ipc snd_hda_ext_core kvm_intel snd_soc_sst_dsp kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_acpi crc32_pclmul snd_soc_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine pcbc snd_hda_intel wl(PO) snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper snd_seq_midi cryptd snd_seq_midi_event intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf hp_wmi cfg80211 input_leds
  joydev snd_rawmidi serio_raw rtsx_pci_ms memstick sparse_keymap wmi_bmof intel_wmi_thunderbolt snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer shpchp snd soundcore idma64 processor_thermal_device virt_dma mei_me int340x_thermal_zone intel_lpss_pci mei intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal intel_lpss acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel intel_pch_thermal mac_hid hp_wireless sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 mmc_block hid_holtek_mouse usbhid hid i915 i2c_algo_bit rtsx_pci_sdmmc drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse drm rtsx_pci ahci libahci wmi pinctrl_sunrisepoint video
 CPU: 2 PID: 762 Comm: kworker/u9:2 Tainted: P        W  OE    4.15.0-45-generic #48-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: HP HP ENVY Notebook/80DF, BIOS F.35 03/04/2016
 Workqueue: hci0 hci_rx_work [bluetooth]
 RIP: 0010:klist_next+0x16/0xd0
 RSP: 0000:ffffa67880ba3ca0 EFLAGS: 00010282
 RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff98c3b12f9800 RCX: 0000000000000000
 RDX: ffffffffc1083e80 RSI: ffffa67880ba3cd0 RDI: 0000000000000000
 RBP: ffffa67880ba3cc0 R08: 00000000000002b6 R09: 0000000000000000
 R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 00000000000002b6 R12: ffffa67880ba3cd0
 R13: ffffffffc1083e80 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff98c3b12f9800
 FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff98c3f1d00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: 0000000000000020 CR3: 000000011840a004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
 Call Trace:
  ? bt_link_release+0x20/0x20 [bluetooth]
  device_find_child+0x5c/0xb0
  ? bt_link_release+0x20/0x20 [bluetooth]
  hci_conn_del_sysfs+0x54/0xa0 [bluetooth]
  hci_conn_cleanup+0x92/0x140 [bluetooth]
  hci_conn_del+0xf1/0x1f0 [bluetooth]
  hci_event_packet+0xe1b/0x2ae0 [bluetooth]
  ? __switch_to_asm+0x40/0x70
  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
  hci_rx_work+0x18d/0x380 [bluetooth]
  ? hci_rx_work+0x18d/0x380 [bluetooth]
  process_one_work+0x1de/0x410
  worker_thread+0x32/0x410
  kthread+0x121/0x140
  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
  ? kthread_create_worker_on_cpu+0x70/0x70
  ? do_syscall_64+0x115/0x130
  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
 Code: 00 0f 1f 40 00 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 89 e5 41 56 41 55 41 54 49 89 fc 53 48 8b 3f 4d 8b 74 24 08 <4c> 8b 6f 20 e8 61 1e 02 00 4d 85 f6 74 6f 49 8b 46 08 49 8d 7e 
 RIP: klist_next+0x16/0xd0 RSP: ffffa67880ba3ca0
 CR2: 0000000000000020
 ---[ end trace 5adb8f6dbbc36567 ]---
 
Package: linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic 4.15.0-45.48
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think anyone will bother because its such an old kernel but also stack traces like that rarely mean much unless you are one of the project dev.

ubuntu is currently using 5.4.0-37 so you should try updates.

FWIW it looks like your bluetooth device is not using the right firmware, possibly because that kernel doesn't recognise its particular configuration.  Updating would be a good move here as you will likely have more usb id's to match or this bug may have been fixed.